# What is the difference between Eclipse for Java (EE) Developers and Eclipse Classic?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

What is the difference between Eclipse for Java (EE) Developers and Eclipse Classic?

Both are marked as version 3.6.

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 38):

If you want to build Java EE applications, it's best to use [**Eclipse IDE for Java EE**](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php). It has editors from HTML to JSP/JSF, Javascript. It's rich for webapps development, and provide plugins and tools to develop Java EE applications easily (all bundled).

[Eclipse Classic](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/classic.php) is basically the full featured Eclipse without the Java EE part.

Comment: Tip: In *theory* you should be able to take the regular _Eclipse Classic_ and install all the other components bundled with the _Eclipse IDE for Java EE_. After all, Eclipse is basically built as a big bag of plugins. But in *practice*, I and many other folks have found that to be impossible. If you need the Java EE features (such as integration with Tomcat or other Servlet engines), switch editions rather than concocting your own upgrade path.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi On the Eclipse comparison page, they have "included (with source)" for the SE version, while only "included" for the EE. What does that mean? Also, everything I'm able to do now with Eclipse SE, will I be able to do with EE?

Comment: @Abdul, it means that the package contains the source code (meaning that you not only get the jars/package, but the source code that you can compile to package to). Don't forget that (some?) Eclipse IDE is an Open Source project so some packages can come with source code.