# Web tool platform vs. Eclipse for Java EE

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-wtp

As far as I know, Web Tools Project is an add-on for a regular Eclipse, that adds all features to turn it in to Eclipse for Java EE. (please correct me if I'm wrong). So my questions are:

- Is it better to have 2 Eclipses (1 regular, and 1 for Java EE), or is it better to simply install Web Tools Project in my regular Eclipse?
- What is the difference between Web Tools Project, or Eclipse for Java EE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Web Tools Platform you are also able to develop Java SE applications, just clicking one button - change perspective(if you want) and it becomes like Eclipse for Java SE. So you dont need to have 2 versions of Eclipse. IAlso this conversation can be helpfull for you [What is the difference between Eclipse for Java (EE) Developers and Eclipse Classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213712/what-is-the-difference-between-eclipse-for-java-ee-developers-and-eclipse-clas). In main case it's the same thing only including extra tools for developing EE applications. Any time you can extend it using plugins. So I recommend you download and install Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers which already includes the Web Tools Platform (WTP)

[Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunasr1)

Comment: Are there any performance differences? any bugs? or anything? or are they 2 exact same things that are coming in different forms?