# New Eclipse use for dynamic web development

Tags: java, eclipse, web, dynamic

I am new to Web Development and Java. I am learning dynamic web development with Java. When I install the Eclipse IDE, which should I install? Eclipse IDE  for Java Developers or Eclipse IDE  for Java EE Developers or Eclipse IDE  for JavaScript and Web Developers. Lastly, should i use gradle or maven? Thank you.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: For dynamic web development with Java use Eclipse IDE for *Java EE Developers*, a similar question answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213712/what-is-the-difference-between-eclipse-for-java-ee-developers-and-eclipse-clas). As for gradle or maven, my university course used maven.

Comment: Opinion based question are off-topic since the answer would be too biased, each developer has its own preference and any ideas presented will just be purely a biased info. This kind of question has no right or wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just learning, I would suggest Eclipse for Java Developers. Java EE has several features that a beginner is unlikely to use, and you want to keep unused features in Eclipse to a minimum, since they do cause Eclipse to start slowly and build programs slowly if you're not careful. I have not tried Eclipse for JavaScript, so I can't tell you anything about it, but you can download anything you need for web development in Eclipse for Java. Look up "eclipse web tools". There are several tutorials on downloading that package.

Whether you use Maven or Gradle shouldn't affect much if you're just learning. I'm personally more familiar with Maven, but both are dependency managers and should meet your needs just fine. My suggestion would be to do a simple tutorial that uses one of the two and just install the dependency manager that the tutorial uses.

Comment: Remember to accept an answer if you feel your question has been answered. That makes it easier for people who are looking for questions to answer.